# Как асинхронно в фоновом потоке выполнить Action<T>?

Tags: c#, async-await

Как асинхронно выполнить `Action<T>` полученный как параметр метода  с помощью Task? Трудности возникают с передачей параметра, или с самим асинхронным вызовом. Например, следующий код никогда не вызывает `FinishLongOperation()`.

```
private async void DoAction(Action<IProgress<string>> action)
{
    PrepareLongOperation(); 
    var progress = new Progress<string>();
    progress.ProgressChanged += (nothing, message) =>
    {
        UpdateStatus(message);
    };

    Task task = new Task(new Action(() => action.Invoke(progress)));
    await task;

    FinishLongOperation();
}
```

При этом, разумеется, передаваемый `Action<T>` имеет вполне конечный код.

Comment: Так "асинхронно" или "в фоновом потоке"?

Comment: @PavelMayorov асинхронно, без разницы в каком потоке.

Comment: Почему-то мне кажется что вряд ли вас устроит выполнение по потоке UI, даже асинхронное :-)

Comment: @PavelMayorov ну без блокировки UI само собой, а метод выполняется на нём.

Comment: Значит, в фоновом потоке (для справки: фоновой поток - это любой поток кроме потока UI)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, Да вы, как всегда, правы, в фоновом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша ошибка - в том, что вы создаете задачу через конструктор, но никогда не запускаете ее (не делаете `task.Start()`).

Но проще всего запускать фоновые задачи с помощью вызова `Task.Run`:

```
await Task.Run(() => action(progress));
```

Comment: А в таком варианте, `FinishLongOperation()` срабатывает раньше, чем заканчивается выполнение `action`

Comment: @4per не верю!.

Comment: Ну и правильно, спасибо. Ошибка, как всегда, не там где ищу. `action` тоже заканчивался асинхронным вызовом, результата которого я ждал вперёд `FinishLongOperation()`...